# Number of possible 5 by 6 matrices from 30 different numbers (without Repetition)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If I am trying to figure how many possible $5\times6$ matrices I can have from $30$ different numbers with no repetition allowed. What I am thinking of is that it will corresponds to $30! = 30\times29\times28\times27\dots \times1$. Is it correct?

I know that with repetition  it will be $30^{30}$.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Placing numbers in a matrix is no different from placing them in a row.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Thank you Mark and Robert